# How do I perform a LIKE % on an array with a GIN-indexed field?

Tags: postgresql

I have an array column `match_input_search_names` that is indexed via a GIN index. When I run the following query, the correct results are returned:

```
SELECT * FROM property_people WHERE search_names @> '{Camel Meal}';
```

However, I would like to search my column using a partial match % like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM property_people WHERE search_names @> '{%amel Me%}';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot be done with full text search.

You should

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

Then you can

```
CREATE INDEX ON property_people
   USING gin (search_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

This index can be used with a condition like

```
WHERE search_names LIKE '%amel Me%'
```